# subprocess.run managing optional stdin and stdout

Tags: subprocess, python-3.5, contextmanager

In python >= 3.5 we can give optional `stdout, stdin, stderr` to  `subprocess.run()`

per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

> Valid values are PIPE, DEVNULL, an existing file descriptor (a positive integer), 
>   an existing file object, and None. PIPE indicates that a new pipe to the child 
>   should be created

I want to support passing through (at least) `None` or existing file objects whilst managing resources pythonically.

How should I manage the optional file resources in something like:

```
import subprocess

def wraps_subprocess(args=['ls', '-l'], stdin=None, stdout=None):
    # ... do important stuff
    subprocess.run(args=args, stdin=stdin, stdout=stdout)
```

Answer (score 0):

A custom `contextmanager` (idea taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6783680/3751373)) seems to work:

```
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def awesome_open(path_or_file_or_none, mode='rb'):
    if isinstance(path_or_file_or_none, str):
        file_ = needs_closed = open(path_or_file_or_none, mode)
    else:
        file_ = path_or_file_or_none
        needs_closed = None
    try:
        yield file_
    finally:
        if needs_closed:
            needs_closed.close()
```

which would be used used like

import subprocess

```
def wraps_subprocess(args=['ls', '-l'], stdin=None, stdout=None):
    # ... do important stuff
    with awesome_open(stdin, mode='rb') as fin, awesome_open(stdout, mode='wb') as fout:
        subprocess.run(args=args, stdin=fin, stdout=fout)
```

But I think there is probably a better way.